# Select Last Inserted Record in SQL Server 2008 using vb.net SqlCommand with CommandType set to Text "NOT USING ANY STORED PROCEDURE"

Tags: sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get last inserted UNIQUEIDENTIFIER in SQL Server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863168/get-last-inserted-uniqueidentifier-in-sql-server-2000)

Here is my table schema

```
CustomersID     uniqueidentifier    (newid())
CompanyName     nvarchar(50)
RegistrantName  nvarchar(50)
AddressLine1    nvarchar(50)
AddressLine2    nvarchar(50)
City            nvarchar(50)
State           nvarchar(50)
Country         nvarchar(50)
Zip             nvarchar(20)
PhoneNo         nvarchar(50)
MobileNo        nvarchar(20)
FaxNo           nvarchar(20)
Website         nvarchar(250)
Email           nvarchar(250)
```

As I'm not using any identity field in my table I cannot use the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the last inserted record id. I need to get the `CustomersID`  after inserting the record. How is it possible?

Comment: @MitchWheat Damn you! Alternatively, since GUIDs are unique, you could always call `NEWID` in advance.

Comment: @MitchWheat: Can you show me a little example?

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=1095 : that's what search engines are for!   :)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I'm confused... How can the identity now be known if it is not issued by the table, but issued by the "inserter"?

Comment: @MarkD: because its a GUID...

Comment: @tech_me : It's almost the same, but I want to do it from VB.NET SqlCommand Class object. And I  think the solution in the link you provided is not applicable for SqlCommand Class object in VB.NET

Comment: This site moderators are much interested in finding duplicates and closing questions than identifying the actual point of question.  x-(

Comment: CODE PROJECT IS MUCH MUCH BETTER SITE THAN STACKOVERFLOW